# Using image generator as y argument in model.fit()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to map images to images, I have done so using image generators. The function model.fit() however wont take, a generator as an argument. Here is my Code:

```
DIR = '/content/drive/My Drive/Datasets/CatDog/dataset/training_set/'
training_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
    )
traininput_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DIR,
    classes = ['cats'],
    class_mode = None,
    target_size= (30,30),
    batch_size = 32
)
trainoutput_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    DIR,
    classes = ['cats'],
    class_mode = None,
    target_size= (60,60),
    batch_size = 32
)

    model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(30,30,3)),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2,2),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2, 2),

    keras.layers.Flatten(),
    keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation= 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation= 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10800, activation= 'relu'),
    keras.layers.Reshape((60,60,3))
])
print(model.output_shape)
assert model.output_shape == (None, 60, 60, 3)
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss = 'MeanSquaredError', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(traininput_generator, y= trainoutput_generator)
```

When I try to train the model i get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-25238523a64d> in <module>()
      1 adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
      2 model.compile(loss = 'MeanSquaredError', optimizer=adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 3 model.fit(traininput_generator,y = trainoutput_generator)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, shuffle, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    890                **kwargs):
    891     if not is_none_or_empty(y):
--> 892       raise ValueError("`y` argument is not supported when using "
    893                        "`keras.utils.Sequence` as input.")
    894     if not is_none_or_empty(sample_weights):

ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input.
```

Comment: I think you are trying to put multiple inputs. Might this help? https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the model.fit documentation

```
 y   Target data. Like the input data x, it could be either
Numpy array(s) or TensorFlow tensor(s). It should be consistent 
with x (you cannot have Numpy inputs and tensor targets, or 
inversely). If x is a dataset, generator, or keras.utils.Sequence
instance, y should not be specified (since targets will be 
obtained from x).
```

In your case x is a generator which provides both images and labels so y should not be specified. You will have to build a custom generator for x such that it provides the input image as the first element of the output tuple and the desired image as the second element of the tuple. Alternatively you can provide x,y as numpy arrays. Below is the code for a generator that should do the job.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
class image_gen():
    def __init__(self, sdir, batch_size,input_size, target_size, shuffle):          
        self.batch_index=0  
        self.sdir=sdir # directory containing input images
        self.batch_size=batch_size   #batch size is number of samples in a batch
        self.target_size=target_size  # tuple (width, height)  for target image 
        self.input_size=input_size   
        self.shuffle=shuffle   # set to True to shuffle images, False for no shuffle
        self.label_list=[] # initialize list to hold sequential list of total labels generated
        self.image_list=[] # initialize list to hold sequential list of total images filenames generated
        self.s_list=os.listdir(self.sdir)   # list of images in directory      
        
    def get_images(self):    # gets a batch of input images, resizes input image to make target images        
        input_image_batch=[] # initialize list to hold a batch of target images
        target_image_batch=[] # initialize list to hold batches of  input images 
        sample_count=len(self.s_list)  # determine total number of images available         
        for i in range(self.batch_index * self.batch_size, (self.batch_index + 1) * self.batch_size  ): #iterate for  a batch
            j=i % sample_count # cycle j value over range of available  images
            k=j % self.batch_size  # cycle k value over batch size
            if self.shuffle: # if shuffle select a random integer between 0 and sample_count-1 to pick as the image=label pair
                m=np.random.randint(low=0, high=sample_count-1, size=None, dtype=int) 
            else:
                m=j   # no shuffle         
            path_to_img=os.path.join(self.sdir, self.s_list[m]) # define the path to the m th image 
            input_image=cv2.imread(path_to_img)
            input_image=cv2.resize( input_image,self.input_size)
            target_image=cv2.resize(input_image, self.target_size) #create the target image from the input image            
            input_image_batch.append(input_image)        
            target_image_batch.append(target_image)        
        input_image_array=np.array(input_image_batch) 
        target_image_array=np.array(target_image_batch)
        self.batch_index=self.batch_index +1         
        yield (input_image_array, target_image_array ) # yield np array of input, labels
```

Below is an example of use

```
batch_size=5
target_shape=(128,128,)
sdir=r'C:\Temp\BIRDS\train\ALBATROSS' # set this to your image directory
shuffle=False
gen=image_gen(sdir, batch_size, target_shape, shuffle) # instantiate an instance of the class
input_images, target_images=next(gen.get_images()) # get a batch of inputs, labels
```

You can use the code below to see the images and targets produced

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig_height=batch_size * 4
plt.figure(figsize=( 10, fig_height))
rows=batch_size
columns=2
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(columns):
        i=row*columns +col
        plt.subplot(rows, columns, i + 1)  
        if col==0:
            img=input_images[row]/255
        else:
            img=target_images[row]/255
        imgplot=plt.imshow(img)
        #plt.axis('off')    
plt.imshow(img)
```

I tried this generator with model.fit with x=image_gen.get_image() etc but for some reason it gives an error that it runs out of images. Working on that